# Issue with angular-based codepen not loading my inline templates using ng-include

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to load angular inline templates as follows:

```
<ng-include src="templateId"></ng-include>
```

Here is the inlined template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="needs.html">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div ng-repeat="need in needs" class="hidden-radios">
        <input type="radio" id="{{need}}" name="needs" ng-required="true" ng-model="advertisement.need" ng-value="need"/>
        <label for="{{need}}" class="col-lg-6">
          <span class="block-span">
            {{ need }}
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

and the relevant portion from the controller:

```
 $scope.focusNeed = function(){
            console.log('focusNeed');
            $scope.templateId='needs.html';
        };
```

See codepen here: http://codepen.io/balteo/pen/ogBBXZ?editors=101

The issue I have is that the app tries to load the template by issuing request on the server instead of looking at the inline templates.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your template is out of scope. Place `<script type="text/ng-template" id="needs.html">` inside `ng-app` and it will work.

In real world `ng-app` is on the `body`. Butin codepen you cannot do that. That is why you'd better use plunker.

Comment: Spot on! Thanks Sergey!